# Fingerprint pattern in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

Does anyone know how to create a fingerprint pattern in Illustrator?

Comment: Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try to create parallel lines and distort them using the twirl, pucker and warp tools.

Answer (score 2):

Put a thin layer of ink on your finger, print onto paper, scan at very high resolution greyscale, place in Illustrator and use Image Trace to vectorise it.

Comment: this is how i'd do it. nothing better than mixing analog with digital.black indian ink is great for this. if you do it onto card you'll get a crisper fingerprint.

Comment: do you really want to publush your fingerprints?